# docker ECR push fails - use of closed network connection

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

I am trying to push an 8 GB image to my private ECR repo but the docker push command keeps failing:

```
docker push <accountnumber>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<repo-name>:latest
The push refers to repository [<accountnumber>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<repo-name>]
9674bf549031: Layer already exists 
2747997b639c: Pushing [>                                                  ]  20.04MB/8.375GB
71b85d15f1d5: Layer already exists 
cd0b79f24bf2: Layer already exists 
bab0e23e8c77: Layer already exists 
7393ae547845: Layer already exists 
8a907b4bbcbf: Layer already exists 
c8ae34277e89: Layer already exists 
a353f0ecb543: Layer already exists 
use of closed network connection
```

In the docker daemon logs I see:

```
Upload failed, retrying: write tcp 192.168.65.3:58566->192.168.65.1:3128: use of closed network connection
```

Comment: `192.168.65.1` by loose convention, `.1` is often a router.  If so, it's doing NAT so `192.168.65.3` can reach `<accountnumber>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.  If it's an ISP provided or other cheap commercially available home router, they're famously flaky and unreliable, and the most common device that will actually start behaving after a hard power cycle.  I suggest you start your investigation there.  You may want to ask on then Networking exchange as well.  If you do, include details about the make and model of the router.

Comment: ok - could a potential solution be to checkout an ec2 instance, ssh into it, and then run the necessary commands there?